# Select Menues, Button Values and Manipulation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, select, dropdownbox

I was wondering if there is any possible way to protect my value attributes assigned to select drop down elements from users who are interested in manipulating the data.

I am simply able to use Firebug and change the values of the items in my drop down and it will submit whatever value I place it in.

Is there a way to lock this down?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can't trust anything coming from the client. If the user attempts to modify record x to have a value of y for field z, you have to validate everything:

1. Does the user have permission to modify record x?
2. Is x in such a state that a modification is allowed?
3. Is y a valid value for field z for record x?

There could be more or fewer validations depending on your business rules.

Basically, you want to ensure that even if the user does tamper with the data, they still have permission to do what they are attempting, and what they are attempting is valid.

Comment: I am thinking a validation is the only way. Basically not allowing submission if a certain field does not equal either x,y, or z. I am trying to implement a drop down for the calendar which will determine the color scheme to that particular event. Problem is, the color values are visible with an editing tools and can be manipulated before submission. This opened my eyes to a lot of data being able to be changed without approval

Comment: Welcome to web development!

Comment: Inspectors like Firebug aren't the only way to tamper with data. There is a valuable tool called Fiddler that lets you see http traffic, which can be very helpful for debugging. But it also lets you capture a request before it goes out and modify anything you want. You could also craft any request you wanted using server-side code.

Comment: LoL..I know. This is the stuff that causes headaches! Wonder how the big boys like FB and others stop this type of activity

Comment: By validating every request and attempted action on the server-side.